# Objective-C truncate tail and showing details when pressing the three dots

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a long text which is truncated to three dots, i want the long text to show a small pop-up that contains the full text when the user clicks on the three dots.

this is the label of the text

```
self.lblTitle.text = self.project.title;
```

[image: here is the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this on using `tapgesture` on the label and on taping the label a `alertview` will show and on that `alertview` you can show the full text what you want to show.

this is how we use tapgesture just example :-

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: in the .xib file or in the code ?

Comment: you can do this by code or xib anything which you prefer

Comment: can you tell me how to add it in the .xib ?

Comment: in xib you take button and on the button the text you were show here give the title of button and on click of button you show alertview

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is add a tapGesture. I've just made this code, you can try use it:

```
- (void)tapGestureToLabel {

    self.lblTitle.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callAlert)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tapGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self.lblTitle addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

}

- (void)callAlert {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:self.lblTitle.text delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

You can call **[self tapGestureToLabel];** right after:

```
self.lblTitle.text = self.project.title;
```

ps: Don't forget to add **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** to your **@interface**